# How to get handle of a known data table

Tags: datatable, ironpython, handle, spotfire

I am hoping to figure out the answer of a seemingly simple question. Below I was trying to get the handle of a known table, by the name of "TableMe". Being able to print its name back on the screen would prove that I have got the handle correctly.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import *

# Trial #1
#dataTable = Document.Data.Tables["TableMe"]

# Trial #2
dataTable = Document.ActiveDataTableReference
print dataTable.Title
```

Both my Trial #1 and #2 had failed, for different reasons:

Trial #1:

```
AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'Tables'
```

Trial #2:

```
AttributeError: 'getset_descriptor' object has no attribute 'Title'
```

I feel that this must be a simple question for any fluent IronPython programmers. Can someone shed a light or two pls?

Comment: What are you using the Spotfire.Dxp.Application for? Without that import Trial 1 will work.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to import anything to access data tables:

```
for table in Document.Data.Tables:
    print table.Name
    print table.Id
    print table.RowCount
    print "---"
```

then to access a specific table:

```
table = Document.Data.Tables["TableMe"]
```

...or if you have the ID:

```
tID = "abc123"
table = Document.Data.Tables[tID]
```

...or by index (refer to the Data Table Properties dialog in Spotfire for the order, make sure to start at zero):

```
table = Document.Data.Tables[0]
```